# Windows batch script X files from one directory to another

Tags: windows, batch

I'm not sufficient at writing any kind of batch script so I kind of mashed up this solution from elsewhere. It does the job; copies files from a directory (and all it's subdirectories) to another directory, seemingly randomly.

However it doesn't manage to copy the complete amount of files and I'm not sure why. If I set it to 10 it returns maybe 7 or 8. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir "D:\Users\...\Music" /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

:: Copy number random files, doesn't get them all though?
for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do call :copyRandomFile

:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"

exit /b

:copyRandomFile
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do xcopy "%%B" "D:\Users\...\Playlists\Random"
exit /b
```

Edit: Sorry, to explain further: I have a folder full of music (though sorted in different sub directories based on artists etc) and I want to randomly select 100 of the files and copy them to my output folder, in order to essentially have a 100 song random playlist to transfer onto mp3 player. The code above does this,but for some reason some it doesn't copy the required amount of files.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What do you want to randomize?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, to explain further: I have a folder full of music (though sorted in different sub directories based on artists etc) and I want to randomly select 100 of the files and copy them to my output folder, in order to essentially have a 100 song random playlist to transfer onto mp3 player. The code above does this,but for some reason some it doesn't copy the required amount of files.

Comment: @HarshalBenake see above

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Windows batch?
If not, [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552764) is a Powershell solution as well as some batch code.

Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem SomeFolder | Get-Random -Count $x | Copy-Item -Destination SomeOtherFolder
```

This assumes you run the script from the folder your files reside. Replace *SomeFolder* with path to your files and *SomeOtherFolder* with your desired destination.

To explain a bit further:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\directory    # Lists content of the directory
                                            # To get subfolders you have to add -Recurse
                                            # to limit this only to files add -Files

Get-Random -Count $x                        # Selects x random items from previous command.
                                            # You have to define $x beforehand

Copy-Item -Destination C:\path\to\destination   # Copies the random selected files to 
                                                # your defined destination
```

You can copy this code in a text file, save as *.ps1 an right klick *run with powershell*.

I might be possible that powershell throws an error like *script cannot be loaded because execution of scripts is disabled on this system*.

If that's the case you have to start powershell as administrator and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

**Note:**
Another drawback I found while testing is that `Get-Random` could get you the same item more than once. [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c6Ty.jpg)

To prevent this I recommend the `Get-Unique` command.

Comment: I tried running this from my documents folder (where I am storing my scripts) and I got the error: 
    Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\...\Music'.
    At D:\...\Documents\makeplaylist.ps1:2 char:1
So I tried adding 
    Set-Location D:\...Music
at the start of the file but still the same error. I don't really want to have to put this ps1 file inside the music folder for it to work.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your path? Either source or destination? If so, you have to put `C:\path\to\folder` in quatation marks (`""`)

Comment: Important Note: I edtited my answer and changed `Move-Item` to `Copy-Item` as the first command moves the files whereas the second copies the files. Apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: I had already changed the Move to Copy as I noted that when you first wrote the answer, but thanks :P Also yes I had a space that was why. However it is still producing strange results, as with the bat script. It copied about 150 files, as well as some empty folders (artist names), rather than the 300 I specified. 

The error is with copy-item, saying an item with the specified name "D:\...\Plsylists\Random\Unknown Album" already exists. Note many of the files I'm trying to copy are within "...\Music\Artist\Unknown Album, though I can't see why this should affect it.

Comment: Without seeing actual errors it sounds like it tries copying directories. You can add the _-File_ switch to _Get-ChildItem_. So `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\directory" -File -recurse | restofscript ... `.

Comment: I tried with my external HDD. Here are stats (without actual copying files):  https://imgur.com/ZeMturr

Comment: Seems to work perfectly now, many thanks! I tried repping the answer but because I'm new apparently it doesn't show - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_source=D:\Users\%YourUserName%\Music" 
set "_target=D:\Users\%YourUserName%\Playlists\Random"

>nul 2>&1 cd /d "!_source!" || =;( endlocal & goto :eof );=

for /f usebackq^tokens^=1-2*delims^=^:^eol^=^| %%G in =;(`
     dir /b /s /a:-d ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /n "^"
    `);= do set "_%%~G=%%~H:%%~I" && set "_max=%%~G"

for /l %%L in =;(0001 0001 0100);= do for /f usebackq %%x in =;(`
       set /a _rage_randon_number^=!random! * %_max% / 32768 + 1
    `);= do echo/!_ran!|%__AppDir__%find.exe "_%%~x" >nul || =;(
         set "_ran=_%%~x,!_ran!" && set /a "_cnt=!_cnt! +1 +0"
        );= && if !_cnt! equ 10 goto %:^)

%:^)
2>&1 =;( 
     cd /d "!_target!" && del /q /f /a: "*.mp3" || mkDir "%_target%"
    );= 1>nul & cd /d "!_source!" 
    
for %%i in =;(!_ran!);= do set /p "'=Copyng: "!%%~i!"" <nul & =;(
    >nul copy "!%%~i!" "%_target%" && echo/Done^^! || echo/Error^^! 
    );= 

endlocal
```

---

**1.** Enter the folder where your files are and list with `findstr` in loop:

```bash
cd /d  "!_source!"  // "D:\Users\%UserName%\Music"

for /f ...(`dir /b /s /a:-d ^| findstr.exe /n "^" )do...
```

---

**2.** With the output of the loop compose the command that defines the variable *`_number=path`* and defines the *`max`* number of files:

```bash
    for...)do set "_%%~G=%%~H:%%~I" && set "_max=%%~G"
```

---

**3.** Create a variable that saves the numbers of the variables that contain the paths randomly and without repetition:

```bash
...)do echo/!_ran!|find "_%%~x" 1>nul || set "_ran=_%%~x,!_ran!" ...
```

---

**4.** limit the loop and *`set _ran=_new-value,!_ran!`* with a counter that increase with each new item added to the variable *`_ran`*, and limit to 10 that files chosen:

```bash
set "_ran=_%%~x,!_ran!" && set /a "_cnt=!_cnt! +1 +0") && if !_cnt! equ 10 goto %:^)
```

---

**5.** Enter your destination folder and delete the mp3 copied in the previous run and if yours doesn't exist yet, create it:

```bash
cd /d "%_target%" && del /q /f /a: "*.mp3" || mkDir "%_target%"
```

---

**6.** When reaching 10 non-repeating numbers in the variable, exit the loop and use the numbers saved in **`!_ran!`** to compose the **`copy command`** of your 10 files ranomically:

```bash
for %%i in (!_ran!)do ... copy "!%%~i!" "%_target% ...
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Copy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Rd | rmDir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)